# Unable to change image from one image to another

Tags: java, android, android-listview, imageview

I have a star image in my activity. Now when the user clicks on that star image, that image should change to **ON Star image**, Same as favorite star image. For this I use the following code :

```
ImageView star=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
 star.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But I am unable to change that image. Please suggest me.

Comment: Use OnClickListener instead of OnTouchListener and simply perform star.setImageResource(..) in the overwritten onClick(..) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OnClickListener instead of an OnTouchListener.

```
ImageView star=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);

        }
    });
```

Your code should look like that. You'll need to make the ImageView clickable as well either in XML (android:clickable="true") or in code (star.setClickable(true);).

Conversely, you could use an ImageButton and set the image as the ImageButton's background. This way you don't have to worry about setting the View to be clickable, as it is inherently clickable.

Comment: Did you set it to clickable?

Comment: yess..did everything..!! I did in xml file and next time in Activity, but same problem..!!

Comment: Tried using an ImageButton instead of ImageView?

Comment: When you used the ImageButton, did you switch the background resource and not the image resource???

Comment: Post your xml as well as your code for the ImageButton please

Answer (score 0):

To change the image you can use this code :

star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use selctor xml. create xml under res/drawable and then create selector_star.xml, your code in that xml should like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_big_on" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_big_off"></item>

</selector>
```

and in your Image view xml, it should like this :

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/star"
 android:background="@drawable/star_selector"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```